# using user defined tables in SQL Stored Procedure - invalid data type

Tags: c#, sql, user-defined-types

I've been struggling to get the defined data table to be accepted as a variable for one of the parameters of the stored procedure.

1st time using user defined tables so I may have made syntax errors

This will be so I can send a data table from a c# program instead of individually inserting each row.

Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Upload_AddBulkProducts]
@uploadedTable CSV_ADDProducts readonly
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Products]
     SELECT * FROM @uploadedTable
GO
```

Error = undefined variable
[The error i get when trying to create the stored procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3ckj.jpg)

User Defined Table

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[CSV_ADDProducts] AS TABLE(
[Product Item] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Product SKU] [bigint] NULL,
[Product Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Product Active] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Product Selling Price] [money] NULL,
[Product Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Product Purchase Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Product VAT Code ID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Product Last Update] [datetime] NULL
)
GO
```

Comment: you cannot pass table name as parameter at all , unless you want to use `dynamic sql`

Comment: @eshirvana thanks ill have a read up on it:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of T-SQL your code is valid. The type can be created and the procedure, too.

Then, in the C# code use the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Product Item", typeof (string));
//add other columns here

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@uploadedTable", SqlDbType.Structured)
{
    TypeName = "dbo.userdefinedtabletype",
    Value = dt
};
sqlComm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: Thanks @gotqn , i just got it to work but not too sure how. would you know how to change the sp to T-SQL query?